# GetFiles and EnumerateFiles skip the foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, fileinfo, getfiles, directoryinfo

When running the following code:

```
var files = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f.FullName)))
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
  {
    file.CopyTo(destPath, true);
  }
```

Where **dir** is a DirectoryInfo
Where **ext** is a List of strings containing accepted file extensions

Upon getting to the foreach loop, files is *null*.
Inside the foreach (at the *in* statement), the program jumps back to the *=>* statement then fills *files*. When it's done, it skips over the foreach loop and never enters it.

I am lost here. Why is my code jumping one line back? I tried Enumerate and GetFiles, none seem to work.

Comment: Maybe the extensions need a dot in the ext list

Comment: That also worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the code "jumping back" is something called [Deferred Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/).  The LINQ expression you have there is not actually executed until the results are used in the foreach loop.

As for skipping over the foreach loop - that happens because the enumeration is empty.  As @Slai mentioned in a comment, there might be a problem with your extension list (forgetting the '.' before the extension name is a common mistake).

If you want the enumeration to execute immediately instead of being deferred (makes debugging easier) the easiest way is just to end your LINQ expression with a .ToList() like so:

```
var files = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f.FullName)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm gonna have to read up on that Deferred Execution. That definitely fixed it. Thank you.